# enabling wireless hardware in ubuntu

Tags: wireless, hardware

**Issue Enabling the Wireless in Ubuntu:**

hardware details :

```
10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 02)
18:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5787M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1693] (rev 02)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Then your broadcom wireless should work (You will need a cable network connection to install)

Note: If your Ubuntu version is 12.04, type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:poliva/pof
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Comment: archer@archer-HP-Compaq-6710b-RJ459AV:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package broadcom-sta-dkms

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version

Comment: My Ubuntu Version is 11.10

Comment: OK, so you just need to use commands that I've added. That repo support Ubuntu 11.10 too