# Cannot get Wireless working by any means on 12.04 (Broadcom Issues)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kernel

I am a linux newbie interested in getting to know my computer a little bit better. The last time I even tried linux was Ubuntu 8.04LTS (Hardy Heron). I am not scared of the terminal but I am not necessarily great at reading it / knowing commands.

I've been having some major issues getting wireless to work on my hardware (Asus g75vw), despite trying many of the workarounds on the site. I've already tried the following methods, all of which lead to replicatable responses.

- Using Additional Drivers (jockey) to ATTEMPT to install "Broadcom STA Driver" which results in a hang on "Installing drivers", which also prevents me from closing jockey at all. **This does not happen when installing nvidia drivers, so it must be the Broadcom STA drivers causing this**.
- Removing `bcmwl-kernel-source` and then installing `B43-fwcutter` and `firmware-b43-installer` and then Commenting "blacklist bcm43xx"
- Installing `bcmwl-kernel-source` in synaptic/terminal which results in a terminal hang on modprobe
- Attempting a `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` which results in a terminal hang at `DKMS: Completed` (which requires me to `sudo dpkg -r bcmwl-kernel-source` at next terminal launch to get back synaptic and apt-get access)
- Attempting to `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms` results in a Program Problem Detected error
- Atempting to install using `bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu0.0.1_amd64.deb` with or without the Ubuntu Software Center results in a Program Problem Detected error similar to the first, and triggers an "Ubuntu has experienced an internal Error" crash.

Any time I attempt to modprobe a wl driver terminal hangs. Other modprobes seem to go through (resulting in a plain `yurt@latria: ~S` line).

I have `sudo reboot`ed after each of these attempts, to no success.

Here are some of my logs in an attempt to get to the root of this issue.

- iwconfig

  ```
  yurt@latria:~$ iwconfig
  eth0      no wireless extensions.

  lo        no wireless extensions.
  ```
- rfkill list all

  ```
  0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: no
      Hard blocked: no
  ```
- lspci

  ```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
  00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ivy Bridge PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
  00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
  00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
  00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
  00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
  00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
  00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
  00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 11a1 (rev a1)
  01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0e0a (rev a1)
  03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 43b1 (rev 03)
  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet (rev c0)
  ```
- lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4

  ```
  yurt@latria:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
  03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
  ```
- Program Problem make error upon trying `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms`

  ```
  DKMS make.log for broadcom-sta-5.100.82.112 for kernel 3.5.0-34-generic (x86_64)
  Wed Jun 26 07:41:36 EDT 2013
  make: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-34-generic'
  Wireless Extension is the only possible API for this kernel version
  Using Wireless Extension API
  Kernel architecture is X86_64
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build/src/shared/linux_osl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o
  /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c:43:24: fatal error: asm/system.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build/src/wl/sys/wl_linux.o] Error 1
  make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/5.100.82.112/build] Error 2
  make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.5.0-34-generic'
  ```
- uname -a

  ```
  Linux latria 3.5.0-34-generic #55~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 7 16:25:50 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
  ```
- sudo lshw -c network

  ```
  *-network        
          description: Network controller
          product: Broadcom Corporation
         vendor: Broadcom Corporation
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
         version: 03
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: driver=wl latency=0
         resources: irq:17 memory:f5400000-f5407fff memory:f5200000-f53fffff
    *-network
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
         vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
         logical name: eth0
         version: c0
         serial: 08:60:6e:10:af:7e
         size: 100Mbit/s
         capacity: 1Gbit/s
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
         resources: irq:45 memory:f5600000-f563ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  ```

I have plenty of screenshots and links to methods I have tried to use to get this to work but I do not have enough reputation to post them I guess so I can send those upon request I suppose.

I am connected to ethernet currently, but would enjoy having wireless enabled. I have **removed** `bcmwl-kernel-source` and am ready to start again clean, so any instructions or help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: have you looked at [How to Install a Broadcom Wireless Driver](http://askubuntu.com/a/60395) or [enabling wireless hardware in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/239539). Besides it seems the driver is already enabled and in work. Are you still not able to connect or connection is dropping very fast. First disable from hardware switch, type `sudo dmesg -c` then again reenable hardware switch and post the content of `dmesg`

Comment: When using the `sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms` package A window pops up saying "System Program Problem detected" and gives me an option to submit a report. Looking at the crash log says it fails in a `make` operation.

I have also similarly tried to do the first link's process with no luck at all.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure exactly how to disable my driver from a hardware switch -- I don't think I have one. Unless you mean a direct keyboard key or something?

Comment: Yea keyboard key or external key any one. I think that is not the problem, problem is with `make` utility used for compilation.

Comment: I posted my dmesg log but I'm not sure how to fix this if the make utility is constantly breaking. It installs other software fine.

Comment: Looks like you are using newer kernel :( that is why that patch is not working. Also include kernel information in question `uname -a`. What wonders me, your `rfkill` shows there is no hard block means it did recognize the hardware and a driver is working. remove dmesg, it is useless, include result of `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: There, added the two you requested, does it give any better information? I don't have any networks (or any indicator that the wireless is working) showing up despite my windows PC right next to me (And my parents mac) recognizing our wireless network AND my neighbor's.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/251163/is-there-a-way-to-get-broadcom-802-11ac-wifi-43b1-working-on-ubuntu-12-10 There appears no way, so far, to get this device working.

Comment: Thank you for your help -- is there any hope in the future for me or am I out of the Linux game until I can buy new hardware?

Comment: The future is a vague term. I'm sure, if you define future as in the next five or ten years, then, yes, I'm certain the device can be made to work. On the other hand, there are lots of inexpensive USB wireless devices available that work immediately. A search here and at ubuntuforums.org will show many discussions about this.